# Highcharts x-axis tick starts with an offset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to remove the `offset` on the tick of the `x-axis`.

I want the first tick `10/8` to start from the `x-axis` and `y-axis` intersection.

`10-8` should be on the marker which is between the two labels.

I have following code for it in highchart.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            title: {
              text: title_x_axis,
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
              },
              formatter: function(){
                return "<h3><b>" + this.value + "</b></h3>";  
              }
            },
            min: 0,
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            align: "left"               
        },
```

Max padding and min padding are set to 0, So I don't know what the problem is?

**EDIT:**

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edrjs1r4/1/) of the type of chart I am dealing with.
Note Image below has different x-axis values as I am not using the same value of fiddle.
Also I have set `tickmarkPlacement: "on"` after I took that snapshot.
I want `Jan` label to start from the beginning of line. It has some offset currently.

[image: Highchart x-axis offset]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Based on the lines on your xAxis, your data points appear to be contained mid-way between each point. This means that your xAxis doesn't have an offset and does in fact start on the tick. Are you able to replicate this graph on http://JSFiddle.net?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: I have edited the question can you have a look at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use (assuming 'categories' is your array of categories)

```
 min: 0.5,
 max: categories.length-1.5,
 startOnTick: false,
 endOnTick: false,
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/27hg0v06/1/

Use newset version of highcharts to get fully working tooltip:

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: In this jsFiddle, the data literally goes off the chart in the y-direction.  I'm guessing because the formatter is looking one data point behind due to the `.length - 1.5` parameter.  How can you stop that from happening but still have the end-to-end effect the OP is looking for?

Comment: @pshep123 Are you referring to the JSFiddle demo in the answer? Data is not off in the y-direction and `.length - 1.5` is about xAxis (left and right), so has nothing to do with y-direction (up and down). Please collaborate or maybe open a new question.

Comment: I'm using this code but it is not working if the value is 2. Any ideas?

Comment: @AllanJebaraj I assume that you are using 2 categories. Changing min to 0.499 will resolve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6v0578x1/3/ If I have assumed wrongly please provide more info and a live demo for the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Add pointPlacement: 'on' in plotOptions.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
     pointPlacement: 'on'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the tickMarkPlacement property:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

By default, it is 'between', which is what you are seeing on your chart.

Setting it to 'on' should do what you need.

You can look at the minPadding and maxPadding properties in addition to the tickMarkPlacement:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding

Comment: Yaa 'tickmarkPlacement: "0"' it got the label on marker, But how can I change the position to start of x-axis?

Comment: If you combine these properties with the endOntick/startOnTick, min/max as mentioned in Kacper's answer on this page, you should be able to fully control every aspect of the axis start/end point.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Fiddle:**

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            tickInterval: 1,
            tickmarkPlacement: "on",
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            offset: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            findNearestPointBy: 'x',
            label: {
              connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointPlacement: 'on'
          }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**You Just Need to Add the following before series object:**

```
plotOptions: {
          series: {
            findNearestPointBy: 'x',
            label: {
              connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointPlacement: 'on'
          }
        },
```