# How we configure highchart x axis start from first tick?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am learning highchart with angularJs,  first tick of x axis is not starting from 0 or we can say that left most corner of chart, here I attached screen shot of output which I am having now,

[image: Line chart Image - not x axis first tick start form left most corner.]

[image: Column chart view - not x axis first tick start form left most corner.]

For this I refer **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364906/highcharts-x-axis-tick-starts-with-an-offset)** which worked but **not working properly when only 2 values are there on x-axis it displayed 0.5 only on center on x axis, not showing actual value.**

I am doing like this in my example,

```
xAxis: {
                  labels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.value; 
                            }
                        },
                        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        minPadding: 0,
                        maxPadding: 0,
                        startOnTick: true,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        align: "left",
                        lineColor: 'transparent'
                    }
```

Can anyone please guide me for the same.?

Comment: Can you make a live example of the problem? You can modify this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/27hg0v06/1/

Comment: sure, please check this for more details, http://jsfiddle.net/Gauravr/27hg0v06/131/

Comment: It might be tricky to customise axis categories in that way - it look that you have better control over ticks, min, max in linear axis - so you can use a linear axis and use categories for axis labels and points' names -  http://jsfiddle.net/27hg0v06/133/

Comment: yes, that is looking batter. Thank you @morganfree for your valuable time for this solution.

Comment: @morganfree If I want to hide x axis line (only horizontal line), for that I uses  lineColor: 'transparent'  it works for line chart but not working for Column chart. Can you please give me solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

**Add the following for the required functionality, it will start from leftmost point** :

```
plotOptions: {
          series: {
            findNearestPointBy: 'x',
            label: {
              connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointPlacement: 'on'
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think set Y-axis min value and X-axis min value.

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
      return this.value;
    }
  },
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  min: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
  align: "left",
  lineColor: 'transparent'
},
yAxis: {
  min: minYAxisValue,
  max: maxYAxisValue
}
```

Hope so it may be helpful..

Comment: can you please update this thing in this fiddle.?  jsfiddle.net/Gauravr/27hg0v06/131